# Getting a list of tasks from a esxi host using c#

Tags: c#, vmware, esxi

I have a single esxi without the use of vCenter.  Is it possible to use TaskManager along with CreateCollectorForTasks to retrieve all tasks that are occurring on this one system?  Or do I have to just use the vm.recentTask to get that information? 
When I use the recentTask I get the following when I power on a VM:

```
Task-ha Task-3-vim.VirtualMachine.powerOn-183533404
```

What does the 183533404 indicate?

If I can use the Task Manager can someone please show me how to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: The simplest way to tell if it's supported is to browse the ESXi's Managed Object Browser (MOB) at https://<esxi ip>/mob. Then browse to `ServiceContent` and see what you find. If you haven't used the MOB before then invest some time in learning about it because it's crucial when consuming the vSphere API. Assuming `TaskCollector` is present for ESXi, then you can find sample programs on how to use it such as [this one](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/520597). Lastly, what are you trying to accomplish? There might be a better way to go about it.

Comment: @YSK thanks for this information.  I did in the past go through the mob but did not know what its purpose is. I think I need to learn this.  What I'm trying to do is to rebuild the C# client for two reasons, 1- to learn C# a bit more and 2- to learn the inner of vSphere.

Comment: Re-building the C# client is no small feat - there are many dark corners to the vSphere API. You absolutely want to be friends with the MOB in order to do that. It will help you immensely in exploring the vSphere inventory and its APIs.

Comment: Thanks @YSK this info helped a lot.  I'm getting somewhere.  I now have another problem that I will ask in a new thread.